# How to add Tags Filter in wordpress admin dashboard

Tags: posts, filters, tags

How to add filter by Tags in wp admin dashboard?

There are option for category and date filter but not tags filter. I want to filter wp post by tags.

Did from many forum but didn't work.

I am non-coder. pls suggest.

Comment: Good answer below. Also, you can click the name of the tags/categories that are displayed near the post's title / other info on the 'All Posts' page (/wp-admin/edit.php) or, simply type the tag into the url: `/wp-admin/edit.php?tag=test`

Answer (score 1):

Done Successfully from this coding.
Inserted ***wp-includes/function.php***

```
function kc_add_taxonomy_filters() {
global $typenow;

// an array of all the taxonomyies you want to display. Use the taxonomy name or slug
$my_taxonomies = array(  'post_tag' );
switch($typenow){

    case 'post':

        foreach ($my_taxonomies as $tax_slug) {


                    $tax_obj = get_taxonomy($tax_slug);
                    $tax_name = $tax_obj->labels->name;
                    $terms = get_terms($tax_slug);
                    if(count($terms) > 0) {
                        echo "<select name='$tax_slug' id='$tax_slug' class='postform alignleft actions'>";
                        echo "<option value=''>Show All $tax_name</option>";
                        foreach ($terms as $term) {
                            echo '<option value="', $term->slug,'" ',selected( @$_GET[$tax_slug] == $term->slug , $current = true, $echo = false ) , '>' , $term->name ,' (' , $term->count ,')</option>';
                        }
                        echo "</select>";
                    }

        }


    break;
}
}
```

Now,Insert child theme ***folder/function.php***

```
add_action( 'restrict_manage_posts', 'kc_add_taxonomy_filters' );
```

Thanks.